# How do I put my app in Standby mode on Android M

Tags: android

I can't seem to put my app in Standby mode.
I put the following command:

```
adb shell am set-inactive <packageName> true
```

Along with the package name (after extracting it from `pm list packages -f`) but I'm always getting the message:

> "The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 0):

This looks an environment problem (not something specific to Android M) I would first check if the build-tools are at the latest version

Answer (score 0):

You must remove `<>` .

Like this:

```
adb shell am set-inactive com.xxx.demo true
```